# What format of large background image provide in jar?

Tags: java, swing, jar, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have Java Swing application with maximized bounds for `JFrame`. The application is distributed as jar file up to now.

Initially for background image I have used some large arbitrary image file of `png`-format. And I do have a code which can load and set image as background for `JFrame`.

Now, I got a new image from designer in both `cdr` and `png` format. Png image is 5 by 4 thousand pixels now.

My requirements:

1. to minimize image file size
2. to support different screen resolutions

**What would be the best option to meet requirements?**

- Resize file to 1920x1080 and keep as `png`, and resize at runtime to smaller images if needed according to resolution
- Keep file as `cdr` or some other vector format. But I am not sure Java can easily read and convert it to `BufferedImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What would be the best option to meet requirements?**
>
> Resize file to 1920x1080 and keep as `png`, and resize at runtime to smaller images ..

..or *larger* - time goes on, screen resolutions get bigger (& bigger)..

> .. if needed according to resolution.

Yes.  I think that is the best option.

Loading a library to render an SVG or EPS to `BufferedImage` at run-time seems like overkill for a BG image.

### Deployment

> The application is distributed as jar file..

Applications that use images often have a GUI.  Does this app. have a GUI?

If so, it would be optimal to deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

The Jars for JWS can be downloaded lazily and programmatically, and are refreshed when updated, so the image should probably be in a separate Jar of its own to avoid downloading a new version every time there is a bug fix.  When putting an image (or compressed media files in general - sound, video,..) use 'no compression'.  Zip does nothing good for these already highly optimized, or at least very specialized, data formats.

Comment: Yes, I have deployed it as JWS now. I have one background image and many small items, i.e. cards. Why it should it a jar, not just folder at server? Should I make two separate jars for bg and other images or package all in one?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the opportunity to get the file in `.svg` this will fit your needs the best. You could then have a look at [Apache's **Batik**](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) library and its rasterizer to render the image.

Comment: What is the most general approach? Why svg and not eps?